# Spring boot Kafka metrics configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a spring boot microservice using **spring-kafka**. There are a couple of Kafka listeners and producers and the Kafka related metrics are successfully presented at the actuator endpoint. But when adding another maven dependency with custom metrics, the Kafka related metrics provided by spring boot are removed. I suspect it's related to introducing new **MeterRegistry** bean, but overriding it with the same bean definition as in **NoOpMeterRegistryConfiguration** in **spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure** module of **spring-boot** didn't help. I've also tried debugging **KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration**, and it looks like all the beans are successfully instantiated. Can somebody with more experience with **spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure** help me to understand the default configurations for Kafka related metrics, please?

The spring configuration in the new maven dependency is pretty simple, just ProducerFactory and MeterRegistry beans are defined

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory(MessageCounter messageCounter) {
    Map<String, Object> configs = this.kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
    configs.put("interceptor.classes", Collections.singletonList(RecordSuccessfullySentInterceptor.class));
    configs.put("message.counter.bean", messageCounter);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configs);
    producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix(this.transactionId);
    return producerFactory;
}

@Bean
public MeterRegistry meterRegistry() {
    return new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
}

@Bean({"retryProducerFactory"})
public ProducerFactory<Object, Object> retryProducerFactory(MessageCounter messageCounter) {
    Map<String, Object> configs = this.kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
    configs.put("interceptor.classes", Collections.singletonList(RecordSuccessfullySentInterceptor.class));
    configs.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    configs.put("message.counter.bean", messageCounter);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Object, Object> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(configs);
    producerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix(this.transactionId);
    return producerFactory;
}
```

It may be possible some transient dependency is messing up spring boot autoconfiguration for Kafka related metrics though.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the usages of , e.g., `DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer` which beans are defined in `KafkaMetricsAutoConfiguration`, you'll see that it is only used in one place - `KafkaAutoConfiguration`.

And having a closer look here:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ProducerFactory.class)
public ProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory(
        ObjectProvider<DefaultKafkaProducerFactoryCustomizer> customizers) {...}
```

we see that this thing is invoked only when `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ProducerFactory.class)`. Meaning that if you define a `ProducerFactory` yourself, this is not invoked and `ProducerFactory` is not customised with metrics listener (e.g., `MicrometerProducerListener`).

In this case the easies thing is to add

```
factory.addListener(new MicrometerProducerListener<>(meterRegistry));
```

when instantiating a factory. Similarly for consumers.